# Failed to Deploy Android Xamarin Forms Application After Adding Splash Screen

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

For a couple days I tied to implement the splash screen on Android Xamarin Forms Application, I tied many approaches but all failed in the same way,
The application before adding the splash screen is working fine,
After adding the splash screen i get this error message

> ```
> 3>------ Deploy started: Project: NoorAlEman.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 3>Error: Cancelled
>
>
> ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== 
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

sometime the application run without showing the splash screen for one time only if i delete "bin" and "obj" folder and rebuild the solution and most of other time it keeps showing the same error message.
I am sure about adding all files using visual studio 2019 interface, also all files have
Build Action: AndroidResource
Copy to output directory:  Do not copy "Also i tried to make it as copy always"
Custom tools: I tried to leave it empty and other times i set to "MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles"
Other thing i done is to set the MainLauncher to false in the manactivity.cs and setting it to true in the splashsctivity.cs
I tried these tutorials and all ended up showing the same error

(1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

(2) https://progrunning.net/best-way-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-xamarin-forms-android-project/

(3) http://ebubekirsezer.com/en/xamarin-forms-splash-screen/?unapproved=11607&moderation-hash=67d1307ecdd13ca8e5b0acceae43d22d#comment-11607

Please do you have any suggestion that might resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance
M. Mazin

Comment: If you Clean Solution, then Quit VS, then open & build/run again, does it work once?

Comment: Can you show the code of the splash screen activity? Or you can try to use the [splach screen api of the android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create a new activity, say `SplashActivity` with the following attributes `[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash", NoHistory = true)]`, where the Theme would be an image, or whatever you want your splashscreen to be. Then inside you just start the main activity of your application, something like this:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `MainLauncher` attribute from the MainActivity.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution was:
-rebuilding the project
-closing and reopening VS
-disconnecting and reconnecting my mobile device

I don't know where this error comes from, and it's a real pain, but this way you can at least keep testing your app until there comes an update which fixes it.